# Extra scrollbar how can i remove it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hello i have some problem for some reason there a extra scroll bar appearing, where it didnt happen before when i was doing debugging and testing however after i push and commit to github i realzie there an extra scroll bar as i am using KendoGrind for it for infinte scroll bar originally

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Favicons -->
        <link rel="icon" href="../../assets/images/icon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" href="../../assets/images/icon-192x192.png">


    
        <!-- Bootstrap, jQuery & Popper -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!--Bootstrap style min css cant load -->
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Kendo UI -->

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

        <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1109/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1109/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1109/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1109/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    





        <!-- Icons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>

        <!-- Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/styles/style.css">
        <!-- Components -->
        <script src="../../assets/js/navbar.js"></script>

        <script src="../../assets/js/table_row_highlight.js"></script>

        <!-- load the spinner loader / option ?-->
        <script src="../../assets/js/manageCustomer.js"></script>



        <!-- Global Script -->
        <script src="../../assets/js/global.js" defer></script>


        <title>Eco Exchange - Manage Customers</title>

        <style>
            /*Button style */
            .custom {
            width: 120px
            }

            .highlight {
            background-color: lightgray;

            }

            .table-responsive{
                padding-top: 50px ; 
                
            }
            .picture{
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            
            }
            /* Basically style of the grind table td  */
            div.k-grid td  {
                border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray  ;
                border-top:  1px solid lightgray  ;
            }   
            
            /* Basically style of the grind header    */
            .k-grid .k-grid-header .k-header{
                background-color: white;
                font-size: 18px;
                font-weight: bold;
        
            }
            /* Basically style of the grind bottom  */
            .k-grid  {
                border-bottom: solid lightgray;
                
        
            }
        

        
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <main>
            <!-- Basically a white rectange inside-->
            <div id="main-container">

                <!-- Navigation bar-->
                <div id="navbar"></div>
                <div id="main-content">
                    <div id="container-head">
                        <!-- .header-side-elem is used to centre the header logo -->
                        <img class="header-side-elem" id="header-logo" src="../../assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
                        <h3 id="header-text">Manage Customers</h3>
                        <div class="header-side-elem" style="width:120px;"></div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- the white rectange body contain-->
                    <div id="container-body">
                        
                        
                    <div class="col-12">

                        <br />
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <!-- Search bar components -->
                                <span id="search-icon" class="fa fa-search search-icon-span"></span>
                                <input class="search-input form-control" placeholder="Name" type="text"
                                    name="Customer Name" id="search-customer-name">
                            </div>
                            
                            <!-- button all of it-->
                            <fieldset class='btn-group'>

                                <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn custom mr-3" style="border-radius: 5px;">Add </button>

                                <button id="view" type="button" class="dark view btn btn-primary btn custom mr-3 disabled change-row" style="border-radius: 5px;" disabled>View Details</button>

                            </fieldset>
                            
                            
                            <div class="col-md-10">

                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="customer-list" class="table">
                                        <!-- Loading Spinner Div -->
                                        <div id="loading-container">
                                            <p>Fetching all customer data...</p>
                                            <div id="loading-spinner">
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <tbody>
                                            
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                
                    <!--AJAX call database-->
                    <script>
                        
                        $.ajax({

                            url: "https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8090/api/get",

                            method: "GET",
                            // In this case, we are going to use headers as
                            headers: {
                                // The query you're planning to call
                                // i.e. <query> can be UserGet(0), RecyclableGet(0), etc.
                                query: "CustomerGet(0)",

                                // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
                                apikey: sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
                            },



                            success: function (data, xhr, textStatus) {
                                //console.log(data)
                            
                                
                                const buildTable = data => {
                                        const table = document.querySelector("#customer-list tbody");
                                        

                                        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                            let row = 
                                            
                                            `
                                                    
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td class="cell-customer-name"><img src = "${data[i].Picture}" class="picture" ></img></td>
                                                    <td class="cell-customer-name" style="padding-right: 80px; padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">${data[i].Name}</td>
                                                    </tr>`;
                                            
                                            table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', row);
                                            
                                        }
                                    };

                                    // Fetch method
                                    const getData = async (url) => {

                                        const response = await fetch(url, {
                                            method: 'GET',
                                            headers: {
                                                query: "CustomerGet(0)",
                                                // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
                                                apikey: sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
                                            }
                                        });
                                        const json = await response.json();
                                        $("#loading-container").hide();
                                        return buildTable(json);
                                    };
                                    getData('https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8090/api/get')
    
                                    

                            },

                            error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                            });
                    </script>

                    <!-- Search bar  function -->
                    <script>
                        $("#search-customer-name").on("keyup change", function() {
                            var customername = $("#search-customer-name").val().toLowerCase();
                            
                            console.log(customername);
                            if (customername == "") {
                                $('#customer-list tbody tr td.cell-customer-name').parent().show();
                            } else {
                                $("#customer-list tbody tr").filter(function() {
                                    var customernameText = $(this).children("td.cell-customer-name").text().toLowerCase();
                                    
                                
                                    $(this).toggle(
                                        (customernameText.indexOf(customername)>=0) 
                                    );
                                })
                                
                                    };

                                
                                })
                    </script>
                    <!--Kendo UI Endless scrollbar -->
                    <script>
                    $("#customer-list").kendoGrid({
                        height: 550,
                        scrollable: {
                            endless: true,
                        },
                        
                        columns: [
                            { 
                                field: "Profile",  
                                width: "12px",
                                
                                
                            },
                            { 
                                field: "Name",  
                                width: "100px" 
                            },
                         
                        ],

                    });
                    
                    </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>

        <footer>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <img src="../../assets/images/wave.png" alt="">
        </footer>
    
        
        <script>
            // This global value it used to properly highlight the page name for the navbar
            const CURRENT_TAB = "manageCustomers";
        </script>
        <!-- Feather replace to enable feather icons -->
        <script>
            feather.replace();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the original testing picture that i have done
[image]

after i have pull and push it became like this
[image]

there an extra scroll bar why is this happening needed help as i look through my code and didnt find any thing i have added or miss

Comment: Do you have an online website?

Comment: You can always use `overflow: hidden` in CSS prevent scrolling, if you need to. However, I'm not sure this is the result you want.

Comment: yes it work  <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow: hidden;">
i decide just hide the extra scroll bar from this div as it seems it come from here

Answer (score 0):

This make my extra scrollbar in my div gone for now which is what i want

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="overflow: hidden;">
```